# Multiplication formula in Grassmannian cluster categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, grassmannians, cluster-algebras

Grassmannian cluster categories are studied in [A categorification of Grassmannian cluster algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7301) and [Cluster categories from Grassmannians and root combinatorics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05181). The category $CM(B_{k,n})$ of Cohen-Macaulay modules over certain algebra $B_{k,n}$ is an additive categorification of the Grassmannian cluster algebra $\mathbb{C}[Gr(k,n)]$. A cluster character $M \mapsto \psi_M$ on the Grassmannian cluster category $CM(B_{k,n})$ is defined in Definition 9.1 [A categorification of Grassmannian cluster algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7301).

I think that the following multiplication formula is true:

For any Auslander-Reiten sequence $\tau M \to N \to M$ in the Auslander-Reiten sequence of $CM(B_{k,n})$, 
$$
\psi_{\tau M} \psi_M = \psi_N + \prod_i \psi_{P_i},  \quad (1)
$$
where $P_i$ are some projective modules in $CM(B_{k,n})$ (they corresponds to frozen variables in $\mathbb{C}[Gr(k,n)]$). 
Is the formula (1) already known in literature? Thank you very much.